# parsing json file with function into dataframe for analysis

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Hi am working with two json files , and im having problem with the data cleaning.

Suppose a record in g1j or g2j looks like this:

```
{
    'cls_loc': 'QOEBBG_K0101',
    'date': 1584957443013,
    'dur': 32,
    'exp': [
        {
            'm': 'spot_excited',
            's': 8.5,
            't': 8.5,
            'w': 'spot_bored',
            'x': 'A'
        },
        {
            's': 1.1, 
            't': 11.4, 
            'w': 'spot_scared', 
            'x': 'A'
        }
    ],
    'mod': 'Poster',
    'pre': False,
    'scr': 67,
    'usr': 'QOGOBN',
    'ver': '20.5.3'
}
```

What we want per row in our DataFrame is this:

```
{
    'student_pin': 'QOGOBN',            # from `usr`
    'date': datetime.date(2020 3, 23),  # from `date`, but parsed
    'duration': 32,                     # from `dur`
    'level': 3,                         # the "K" from `cls_loc`, mapped to int
    'unit': 1,                          # from `cls_loc`, mapped to int
    'module': 1,                        # from `cls_loc`, mapped to int
    'accuracy': 0.5,                    # calcualted from `exp`
}
```

my code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/group1_exp_2020-04-08.json', 'r') as f:
    g1j = json.loads(f.read())

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/group2_exp_2020-04-22.json', 'r') as f:
    g2j = json.loads(f.read())

#convert the integer timestamp to a datetime.date

def timestamp_to_date():
    l =[]
    for item in g1j:
        timestamp =item['date']
        timestamp = timestamp/1000
        dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y, %m, %d ')
        l.append(dt_obj)
        
    return l

timestamp_to_date()

def timestamp_to_date():
    l =[]
    for item in g2j:
        timestamp =item['date']
        timestamp = timestamp/1000
        dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y, %m, %d ')
        l.append(dt_obj)

    return l

#extract the level, unit, module, and accuracy here
def get_level(x):
    loc = x['cls_loc'].split('_')[-1]
    return level_map[loc[0]]

def get_unit(x):
    loc = x['cls_loc'].split('_')[-1]
    unit = loc[1:3]
    return int(unit)

def get_module(x):
    loc = x['cls_loc'].split('_')[-1]
    module = loc[3:]
    return int(module)

def get_accuracy(x):
    challenges = [x for x in x['exp'] if x['x'] == 'A']
    n = len(challenges)
    if n == 0:
        return 'N/A'
    mistakes = [x for x in challenges if 'm' in x.keys()]
    correct = n - len(mistakes)
    return correct / n

#create the function to convert experience records to the pandas.DataFrame
def exp_to_df(g1j):
    df = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['exp'])
    return df

def exp_to_df(g2j):
    df = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=['exp'])
    return df

#uses the function you just implemented, and checks that your function keeps the records and uses the right column names
g1 = exp_to_df(g1j)
g2 = exp_to_df(g2j)

assert len(g1) == len(g1j)
assert len(g2) == len(g2j)
columns = ['student_pin', 'date', 'level', 'unit', 'module', 'accuracy']
assert all(c in g1.columns for c in columns)
assert all(c in g2.columns for c in columns)
```

What am I doing wrong? It  seems like `def exp_to_df(g1j)` and `def exp_to_df(g2j)` are wrong. Any suggestions?

Also is my `def timestamp_to_date()` also wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the pandas [**`read_json()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) function to load your json directly into a dataframe (I added a couple dummy records):

```py
g1 = pd.read_json('/content/drive/MyDrive/group1_exp_2020-04-08.json')

#         cls_loc                     date  dur                                                exp     mod    pre  scr     usr     ver
# 0  QOEBBG_K0101  2020-03-23 09:57:23.013   32  [{'m': 'spot_excited', 's': 8.5, 't': 8.5, 'w'...  Poster  False   67  QOGOBN  20.5.3
# 1  QOEBBG_K0102  2020-03-23 09:57:23.013   32  [{'m': 'spot_excited', 's': 8.5, 't': 8.5, 'w'...  Poster  False   67  QOGOBN  20.5.3
# 2  QOEBBG_K0103  2020-03-23 09:57:23.013   32                  [{'s': 1.1, 't': 11.4, 'x': 'C'}]  Poster  False   67  QOGOBN  20.5.3
```

Then you can do all the data wrangling with pandas functions like
[**`str.extract()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html),
[**`assign()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html),
[**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html),
[**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), and
[**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```py
# extract level, unit, module as columns
g1 = g1.assign(**g1.cls_loc
    .str.extract(r'_([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})')
    .rename({0: 'level', 1: 'unit', 2: 'module'}, axis=1))

# convert date to datetime
g1.date = pd.to_datetime(g1.date, unit='ms')

# map level to int
level_map = {'K': 3}
g1.level = g1.level.map(level_map)

# compute accuracy
def accuracy(exp):
    challenges = [e for e in exp if e['x'] == 'A']
    n = len(challenges)
    if n == 0:
        return np.nan
    mistakes = [c for c in challenges if 'm' in c.keys()]
    correct = n - len(mistakes)
    return correct / n
g1['accuracy'] = g1.exp.apply(accuracy)

# rename usr -> student_pin
g1 = g1.rename({'usr': 'student_pin'}, axis=1)

# keep desired columns
columns = ['student_pin', 'date', 'level', 'unit', 'module', 'accuracy']
g1 = g1[columns]
```

Output:

```
   student_pin                     date  level  unit  module  accuracy
0       QOGOBN  2020-03-23 09:57:23.013      3    01      01  0.500000
1       QOGOBN  2020-03-23 09:57:23.013      3    01      02  0.333333
2       QOGOBN  2020-03-23 09:57:23.013      3    01      03       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I tried and it actually worked. I even went ahead and added a dur column.

Comment: How do I change the date to the format 2020-03-23??

Comment: I want 2020-03-23 without the 09:57:23.013

Comment: You can add `.dt.date` to the date conversion line: `g1.date = pd.to_datetime(g1.date, unit='ms').dt.date`